# Flutter : 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1895 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true

Tags: flutter, listview

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        child: StreamBuilder(
                            stream: data.snapshots(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.blue));
                              }
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                return ListView.builder(
                                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: BouncingScrollPhysics()),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    final DocumentSnapshot records = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                                    return Container();
                                  },
                                );
                              }
                              return Container();
                            }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Here is a flutter code as I execute in a `listview.builder` . It worked before I added the `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` property to the `listview.builder` .

I get an error `'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1895 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.`

How can I fix this error

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try providing a fixed height to the `SizedBox` widget. This should resolve the `constraints.hasBoundedHeight` error. You should also try adding a fixed width to your `SizedBox` widget, because your `ListView` has a horizontal scroll direction. This means that your `ListView` might take an unbounded width too.
You should try something like this:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: <some_fixed_height> // you can probably use MediaQuery here
  width: <some_fixed_width>
  child: ...
),
```

Comment: i added `height` in `SizedBox` and it works. thank you

Comment: you can vote the answer up to get more recognition